# Searchbox search in localstorage or html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

this is what I have:
[image]

All the data that you see is saved in the localstorage. What I want now is that you can search and that all the sessions that are not equal to the search terms dissapear.

What is the best that I do? Search in the localstorage or search the html? (jquery/javascript)

HTML code:

```
<div id="content_wrapper" class="">
        <div id="mastersearch" class="container hide">
            <input type="text" id="txtmastersearch">
            <div id="searchresults">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" style="height: 520px;">
            <style>
                h2 {
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                }

                ul {
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                }
            </style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <input id="searchbox" class="span12" type="search" placeholder="Search...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="here" class="row">           

    <div class="span6"><h2 class="before-blocks">Wednesday 3 April 2013</h2><ul id="here" class="sessionlist blocks unstyled"><li class="contentblock has-thumb"><a href="http://test1niels.m.niels.tapcrowd.com/sessions/view/21115">0:00 - 0:00<span class="ellipsis name" style="width: 95%;" '=""><b>tweede</b></span><span class="ellipsis"><em></em></span></a></li></ul></div><div class="span6"><h2 class="before-blocks">Sunday 21 April 2013</h2><ul id="here" class="sessionlist blocks unstyled"><li class="contentblock has-thumb"><a href="http://test1niels.m.niels.tapcrowd.com/sessions/view/21117">12:00 - 15:00<span class="ellipsis name" style="width: 95%;" '=""><b>html5 session</b></span>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best that I do? Search in the localstorage or search the html? (jquery/javascript)

If you are asking about what to choose:

1. get data from LocalStorage;
2. parse DOM;

I that case, I guess, getting data directly from LocalStorage is better solution.
It's logically better, cause html is just presentation layer and getting data from View instead getting it from Model isn't ok.